# Problem following dagger tutorial, section 10 doesn't even compile

Tags: dependency-injection, dagger-2, dagger

I have been trying to follow this tutorial:
https://dagger.dev/tutorial

But I have found several problems with it. The first problems occurs in the section https://dagger.dev/tutorial/01-setup, here we have the following code:

```
      Status unused = commandRouter.route(scanner.nextLine());
    }
```

This makes no sense because the CommandRouter.route() method returns a result:

```
  private final Map<String, Command> commands = Collections.emptyMap();

  Result route(String input) {
```

Not a Status object. I just removed the Status unused and continued.

Now I am trying to follow the instructions on this section:
https://dagger.dev/tutorial/10-deposit-after-login

but I keep getting an error here:

```
    DepositCommand(Database.Account account, Outputter outputter) {
        this.account = account;
        this.outputter = outputter;
    }
```

This code does not compile with the error constructor

```
BigDecimalCommand in class org.example.BigDecimalCommand cannot be applied to given types;
[ERROR]   required: org.example.Outputter
[ERROR]   found: no arguments
[ERROR]   reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

Now the DepositCommand class extends from BigDecimalCommand:

```
final class DepositCommand extends BigDecimalCommand  {
    private final Database.Account account;
    private final Outputter outputter;

    @Inject
    DepositCommand(Database.Account account, Outputter outputter) {
        this.account = account;
        this.outputter = outputter;
    }

    @Override
    public void handleAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        account.deposit(amount);
        outputter.output(account.username() + " now has: " + account.balance());
    }
}
```

And the BigDecimalCommand class has only one constructor argument:

```
abstract class BigDecimalCommand extends SingleArgCommand {

    private final Outputter outputter;

    protected BigDecimalCommand(Outputter outputter) {
        this.outputter = outputter;
    }
```

Has anyone else here faced the same issues with the tutorial?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For BigDecimalCommand to act as the superclass of DepositCommand, you have to [call its constructor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/super.html#:%7E:text=Subclass%20Constructors) using the `super` keyword as the first line of each of your constructors. A reference to a 0-arg constructor is added by default if you don't specify one; here it's trying to call `BigDecimalCommand()`, which does not exist.

The tutorial text is missing the explicit `super` call, but it appears correctly in [the version of DepositCommand that is checked in](https://github.com/google/dagger/blob/21129d963aaadbbaef903e53c9e47f2d32e47308/java/dagger/example/atm/DepositCommand.java#L29-L35) (comment is mine):

```java
  @Inject
  DepositCommand(Outputter outputter, Account account, WithdrawalLimiter withdrawalLimiter) {
    super(outputter);
//  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    this.outputter = outputter;
    this.account = account;
    this.withdrawalLimiter = withdrawalLimiter;
  }
```

As a result, in the version you see checked in, there are two separate `outputter` fields: one in BigDecimalCommand and one in DepositCommand. It's not wrong, but personally I might have chosen to make the BigDecimalCommand `outputter` field `protected` so I could refer toit from `DepositCommand` without having to save it separately.